# retrieving field by name from any Mapper in lift

Tags: lift, mapper

How do we retrieve desired filed from any mapper so as to use it in Query parameter.

In my case i want to find records where my 'desired-field' is having value = somevalue.

It tried the following way

```
foo(Users)

// foo defined here...

def foo ( modelObject:Mapper[_])={

    var field =modelObject.fieldByName("UserName").openTheBox.asInstanceOf[MappedField[_,Users]]
    var requiredUser = modelObject.find(By(field, "dummyUser")

}
```

but then it forces me to specify the actual Mapper in the `asInstanceOf[MappedField[_,Users]]` ( Users instance is passed here ). I want to make it work for any Mapper and not just 'Users'.

It doesn't work with `asInstanceOf[MappedField[_,_]]`

I understand that each Mapper may not have the field that i want and In that case if the `.fieldByName()` function should throw some exception, it's acceptable. But at least for those having the filed, it should work.

can anyone help me in this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def foo[A<: Mapper[A],T](modelObject: A) = {
  val field = modelObject.asInstanceOf[Mapper[A]].fieldByName("userName").openTheBox.asInstanceOf[MappedField[T, A]]
  modelObject.asInstanceOf[MetaMapper[A]].find(By(field, "dummyUser".asInstanceOf[T])
}
```

Can you do something like this when you call:

```
foo[Users,String](Users)
```

Comment: Thanks for this approach. This can work with few minor typecasting changes.                                                                                                                               def foo[A<: Mapper[A],T](modelObject: A) = {
      val field = modelObject.asInstanceOf[Mapper[A]].fieldByName("userName").openTheBox.asInstanceOf[MappedField[T, A]]
      modelObject.asInstanceOf[MetaMapper[A]].find(By(field, "dummyUser".asInstanceOf[T])
    }

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a super method that does all that stuff why don't you pass the lookup function as parameter.

```
def foo[T](find: () => Option[T]) : Option[T] =  find()
```

and call this:

```
foo[User](() => User.find(By(User.userName, "dummy"))
```